# Get SqlCommand local var declaration using Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to get the first `SqlCommand` local declaration from a method body.

Here is my code method declaration visitor:

```
public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    var sqlCommandDeclaration = node.Body.Statements
            .Where(x => x.IsKind(LocalDeclarationStatement))
            .Cast<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Declaration.Type.GetText().ToString() == "SqlCommand");

    base.VisitMethodDeclaration(node);
}
```

Could someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var firstOne = node.Body.Statements
        .OfType<LocalDeclarationStatementSyntax>()
        .FirstOrDefault(syntax => syntax.Declaration.Type.ToString() == "SqlCommand");
```

Comment: It worked in one case, I will check in all methods and classes. Thanks! for now.